# SQL self join result of a select

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, self-join

I have two tables, lets call them `A` and `B` which I perform an `inner join` on.

```
select
A.id, 
A.serial_number as serial, 
concat(B.type, '-', B.primary, '-', B.secondary) as product_number, A.parent_id as parent
from A
inner join B on A.number_id = B.id) as T1
```

as a result I get a set that contains parents and children (1 per parent).

```
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+
| id | serial | product number  | parent |
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+
| 1  |    123 | abc             | null   |
| 2  |    234 | cde             | 1      |
| 3  |    456 | abc             | null   |
| 4  |    895 | cde             | 2      |
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

now I'd like to do a self join to get the following

```
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| id | serial parent | product_number parent  | serial child  | product_number child  |
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| 1  |           123 | abc                    |           234 | cde                   |
| 2  |           456 | abc                    |           895 | cde                   |
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

What would be the best approach for this, I simply couldn't find an easy solution... is there a way to join `T1` with itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's more joins:

```
select
    ap.id as id_parent, 
    ap.serial_number as serial_parent, 
    concat_ws('-', bp.type, bp.primary, bp.secondary) as product_number_parent, 
    ac.child as id_child,
    ac.serial_number as serial_child,
    concat_ws('-', bc.type, bc.primary, bc.secondary) as product_number_child
from a ap 
inner join a ac on ac.parent = ap.id
inner join b bp on bp.id = ap.astrol_number_id
inner join b bc on bc.id = ac.astrol_number_id
where ap.parent is null
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm not really into SQL so I have some gaps here. Could you quickly explain what `a ap`, `a ac` and so on does? Where does the join from `A` on `B` happen?

Comment: @po.pe: these are table aliases. Each table appears twice in the query (once for the child record, another for the parent), so the aliases allow that.